# How to pass bool value from viewbag to jQuery side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I stuck with problem of passing viewbag value from server side to front-end side jQuery, previous examples did not work for me:

```html
var test = '@ViewBag.IsReviewLast'.toString().ToLower();
console.log(test);
```

```html
var myValue = $('#' + '@(ViewBag.IsReviewLast)').val();
```

It`s just return a "ViewBag.IsReviewLast" string value.

There is should be my simple logic:

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
    var test = '@ViewBag.IsReviewLast'.toString().ToLower();
    if (test) {
        //some logic
    }
});

[enter image description here][1]
```

Without brakets it`s also not working.

Comment: `var test = @ViewBag.IsReviewLast` remove single quotes

Comment: @Antihype Bird it`s not working, test gets just ViewBag.IsReviewLast text value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert string to bool in javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var test = ('@ViewBag.IsReviewLast'=='True');
if (test) {
    console.log(test)
    //
  }
});
```